# How to prove this function $f(x):= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k} \exp(2\pi \, i\,k\,x)$ is entire?

Tags: analysis, fourier-series, alternative-proof, analyticity, entire-functions

Given a function which Fourier coefficient decay fast as $k^{-k}$, for example
\begin{align}
f(x):= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^k} \exp(2\pi \, i\,k\,x)
.
\end{align}
How can we prove this function is entire?

Denoting by $R$ the convergence radius of the above power series, recently, I can prove that for arbitrary $r>0$ the convergence radius of the above power series is greater than $r$, i.e. $R >r$. Could I conclude that the function is entire?

Indeed, we have 
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2 \pi \, i \, k)^n}{k^k} \exp(2\pi \, i\,k\,x)
.
\end{align*}
Hence, the Taylor expansion at $x_0$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2 \pi \, i \, k)^n}{k^k} \exp(2\pi \, i\,k\,x)\right] \frac{1}{n!} (x-x_0)^n
.
\end{align*}
It is easy to check that for arbitrary $r>1$ ( by considering the maximum of the function $f(x) = x^n r^{-x}$ and Stirling's inequality)
\begin{align}
\frac{k^n}{r^k} \leq \frac{2^n n!}{(\log r)^n},
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
|f(x)| &\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2 \pi  k)^n}{k^k}\right] \frac{1}{n!} (x-x_0)^n\\
& \leq 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4 \pi)^n r^k}{k^k (\log r)^n}\right]  (x-x_0)^n
.
\end{align}
It is sufficient to consider the last series. By Cauchy theorem, the radius of convergence is given by
\begin{align}
1/R = \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} &=\frac{4\,\pi}{\log r} \lim_{n \to \infty}  \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{r^k}{k^k}\right)^{1/n} = \frac{4\,\pi}{\log r}
,
\end{align}
since the summation converges for any $r$.

We conclude that $R= \frac{\log r}{4\,\pi}$, for arbitrary $r>0$. Thus, the function is entire?

Please give any comment on the proof if you find any bug, or suggest any other solution. I will really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Forgive me, analysis was never my strong point, but can't you use the ratio test to show the radius of convergence is infinite?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why we have to estimate? I applied the ratio test and got the radius of convergence is infinite. By the way, I'm genuinely interested in the question you've asked.

Comment: @Mattos If I use the ratio test then we have to estimate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{n+1}/k^k} {\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{n}/k^k}$, and I get stuck? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Mattos which estimate do you mean?

Comment: I mean for your original series i.e

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \bigg \lvert \frac{(k+1)^{-(k+1)} \exp (2 \pi i (k+1) x)}{k^{-k} \exp (2 \pi i k x)} \bigg \rvert$$

which, using the fact that $\lvert \exp(2 \pi i x) \rvert = 1$, reduces to

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \bigg \lvert \frac{1}{(1 + 1/k)^{k}} \cdot \frac{1}{(k+1)} \bigg \rvert \to 0$$

Comment: As I understand the ratio test is used for power series only? The original series is trigonometric series?

Comment: Like I said before, I'm not great at analysis, so it's best to assume I'm wrong. However, the wikipedia page makes no mention about the types of functions that the ratio test can be used for and the examples used on the page include exponentials.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f_k(z)=\frac{exp(2\pi i z)}{k^k}.$$
Let $R>0$ and assume $|z|\leq R$. We have 
$$|f_k(z)| = \frac{1}{k^k}exp(-2\pi y) \leq \frac{1}{k^k} exp(2\pi R).$$
The numerical series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^k}$$
has the convergence radius $+\infty$ (from the radical test). This implies that $$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{exp(2\pi i z)}{k^k}$$
is uniformly (absolute) convergent on the closed disc $\{|z|\leq R\}$. I guess this implies that $f(z)$ is an entire function, since any compact subset of $\mathbb C$ is a subset in a large enough disc.